# Как пронумеровать строки массива Java?

Tags: java, массивы

Нужно написать метод, который выведет в консоль все элементы массива с новой строки и отобразит его номер в массиве начиная с 1.

Пример вывода:

1. Первый элемент
2. Второй элемент
3. ...

Есть у кого идеи, как это выполнить?
Все перерыл, ничего не смог найти, ниже мои идеи, но они не закончены.

У меня есть два вариант, но в обоих я зашёл в тупик:

1. Тут вроде бы все хорошо, но нужно теперь обьединить все в один массив, при этом значение int представить в виде string

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. А тут можно все представить попроще, но также ругается, что sting не может принять значение int

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему нельзя в одном for вывести i и array[i]?

Comment: Bakhuss, ещё бы знать, как это сделать. Первый день с Java

Comment: Так же, как выводите array[i].

Comment: @IgorTyupanov, если я вас правильно понял, то когда делаете `System.out.println(array[i]);` для массива из `Sring`, то в этом же `for` добавьте строку `System.out.println(i);`

Comment: Постить код надо в текстовом виде, на изображении ничего не видно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать что-то вроде такого:

```
int count = 1;

String [] strings = {"first", "second", "third"};

for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(count + ":" + s);
    count++
}
```

Создать переменную которая будет хранить номер строки, и добавлять ее всякий раз когда печатаете новую строку, а в конце итерации ее инкрементировать.

Можно еще так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(strings[I] + ":" + s);
}
```

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо вам большое. Я немного изменил, но суть остается за вами )

Answer (score 0):

Вывод массива строк с нумерацией элементов:

```java
String [] strings = {"first", "second", "third"};

IntStream
    .range(0, strings.length)
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println((i + 1) + " " + strings[i]));
```

Вывод:

```
1 first
2 second
3 third
```